# Python class member or global variable

Tags: python, class, global

When defining a Python class, class members are like global variables for the class. Then, I do not understand why global variables do exist ? Shouldn t we always use class members instead ?

Comment: I'm not sure I see members as 'global variables for the class', but either way, Python tends not to dictate to programmers, merely recommend. Globals are generally a bad idea, yes, but that doesn't mean they shouldn't exist in the language.

Comment: You said it yourself: class attributes are global *to the class*.  Global variables, on the other hand, are global *to the module*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class members are *like global variables* for the class. Global variables are *like class members* for the module.

It's really that simple.

*P.S. Just in case you are a Java programmer: yes, you can have more than one public class in  your module; yes, you should use this when appropriate.*

Answer (score 0):

And you can program without objects at all :)

Comment: Actually, you can't. Every value your program ever creates is an object. Even if you run an empty program, Python creates numerous objects before even starting with your program. Now, programming without user-defined classes, that's possible, though unlikely to be good style for programs larger than a simple script or single-file library.

Comment: I know :)
But python also have no variables, it have "labels" or "pointers".
Good one anyway +1

Comment: There are "names" and "objects". The only way to get hold of an object is through its name.

Comment: same for int, a = 5 and b = 5 is same object, pointed from two different names. can be prooven via a and b internal ID's. Anyway, I believe my answer give good additional explanation to the asked question.

Comment: @Mike: Not strictly true, you can also access objects by their index or key if their in a some other container object. In addition, the return value of functions and methods don't have to be named to be accessed.

Comment: @martineau: I think `my_list[0]` or `my_dict[key]` is also a kind of a name. More a compound name if you want. At least it would make for a nice consistent view ;). Same goes for function return values. As soon as you call `func()`, you need to put the returned object somewhere: `res = func()` or `my_list.append(func())`. For the latter, we are back to part one of the question. You can argue that if you do functional style programming you don't bother with names for intermediate objects that get created and "consumed" by other functions right away. But in this case you don't really get "a hold

Comment: cont.: "a hold" of an object. I think this name/object approach makes it easier to understand, even though technically you may argue that it is not a name.

Comment: @Mike: You don't _have_ to assign a function result to anything, i.e. `func().append(42)`, although the final result maybe be lost. Otherwise, I think I understand your point(s).

Comment: @martineau: Exactly, as soon as you want to **get a hold** of the 42, you've got to have some kind of name.